# How to unittest prometheus GaugeVec

Tags: unit-testing, go, prometheus

I am new to golang so it's kind of hard to understand what would be the best way to test `prometheus.GuageVec`.

Here is my try 1. where i am trying to get metrics channel. But this request is timing out?

```
    cb, _ := GaugeVecs[name]
    ch := make(chan prometheus.Metric)
    cb.Collect(ch)
    metric := <-ch
    fmt.Printf("%+v", metric)
```

The second try that i did was

```
    cb, _ := GaugeVecs[name]
    err := testutil.CollectAndCompare(cb, strings.NewReader(`expected outcome`), "name")
    assert.Nil(t, err)
```

^^^ this one got error that `parsing expected metrics failed: text format parsing error in line 1: unexpected end of input stream`.

How can i test the output of metric?

Comment: You have to call Collect in a goroutine or buffer the channel, else it is blocked forever when trying to send the metric.

Comment: Your second attempt fails because `"expected outcome"` is not a [valid metric format](https://github.com/Showmax/prometheus-docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md#text-format-details).